# App Insights Workbooks - Is it possible to change the order of the stacked columns?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Currently in Application Insights Workbooks, a stacked barchart is sorted by the "count" value like so:

[image: Barchart with Stacked Columns]

Preferably, I would want to sort the above chart by the duration in ascending order(0-3sec, 3-6sec, etc). Unfortunately `order by duration asc` doesn't seem to have any effect within Workbooks. Is it possible to change the order these are stacked in?

Answer (score 0):

At the current time, no.  It looks like the underlying chart we are using thinks the biggest series is the most important and always does it that way, ordering them by count desc.

Comment: (but i'll investigate more and see if I can do something about it)